# Scroll two horizontal listview and one vertical listview in single activity

Tags: android, xml

I have to scroll both the horizontal listview and vertical listview in single activity.

Below I have posted a screenshot for that:

[image]

**activity_main.xml:**

```
 <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/home_layout_top"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rl_container_scroll"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <include
                android:id="@+id/inc_ads_horizon"
                layout="@layout/ads_horizontal_listview_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

            <include
                android:id="@+id/inc_people_know"
                layout="@layout/people_you_know_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/inc_ads_horizon"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />


            <include
                android:id="@+id/inc_listview"
                layout="@layout/tab_home_list_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/inc_people_know"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/no_user_posts_item_tv"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:text="@string/txt_no_posts_available"
                android:textColor="@color/txt_common_black"
                android:textSize="@dimen/txt_size" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </ScrollView>
```

**tab_home_list_view.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/home_layout_bottom"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lv_post_home_tab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:dividerHeight="5dp"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll"
        android:visibility="gone" />


</LinearLayout>
```

**ads_horizontal_listview_layout.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/rl_horizontalscroll_child"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/rl_horizontalscroll_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp">

    <com.steve.thirdparty.HorizontalListView
        android:id="@+id/hlv_child"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**people_you_know_layout.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/rl_horizontalscroll_second_child"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/rl_horizontalscroll_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp">

    <com.steve.thirdparty.HorizontalListView
        android:id="@+id/hlv_child"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I tried with scrollview.It is not possible to scroll.Let me know is there any other ways to solve this issue.

If I scroll vertical listview to top, it is scrolling vertical listview only.If I am scrolling horizontal listview to the top, it is scrolling both vertical and horizontal listivew.But when I am scolling up, horizontal listview is hiden.

Comment: Use `android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView` in place of `ScrollView`

Comment: Use recyclerview for better scrolling control. http://blog.inapptext.com/recyclerview-creating-dynamic-lists-and-grids-in-android-1/

Comment: @JavaGhost it doesn't solved.If I am scroll vertical listview to top, it is scrolling vertical listview only.If I am scrolling horizontal listview to the top, it is scrolling both vertical and horizontal listivew.But when I am scolling up, horizontal listview is hiden.

Comment: @MohammedAtif ok let me try that one and tell you.

Comment: please explain what you expected from using `wrap_content` as  `ListView` heigth ... for me (and prolly ListView makers too) means that it should be a non scrollable layout with all its children inflated

Comment: @Selvin I can see all the dynamic contents are adding to listview based on arraylist size.Listview also scrolling.But I cant scroll both listvew and horizontal listvew

Comment: You should use `RecyclerView` in place of all three scroll views. To make `RecyclerView` scroll horizontal, you need to set `recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));` and finally add `android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"` to NestedScrollView

Comment: @JavaGhost let me try that one and tell you.If you sure with this, post as an answer.After I go through with your solution, I will accept.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the required views by customizing `ScrollView` & `HorizontalScrollView`.
Can check this post https://arunbadole1209.wordpress.com/2011/10/03/how-to-make-simultaneous-scrollable-views-in-android/

Answer (score 0):

Use this xml layout, customize item views according to your actual need:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <!-- You can define layout manager here also-->
        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/ads_horizon"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            app:layoutManager="android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager"/>

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/people_know"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            app:layoutManager="android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager"/>

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/post_home_tab"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            app:layoutManager="android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```